# Using strftime to create a filename is issue in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, strftime, os.path

I have the following script running in Ubuntu to download images from a web page and save them in to a directory with the current time.

```
import urllib.request
import os
from datetime import datetime, date, time

images = ['https://www.abc.info/a/300.jpg', 'https://www.abc.info/b/301.jpg']

for image in images:
    fullfilename = os.path.join('/home/me/foo/bar/', now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ') + image.split('/')[-1])    
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, fullfilename )
```

I want to replicate it in windows. The following code does't wok and this is what it says:

```
fullfilename = os.path.join(r'''C:\Users\me\foo\bar''' , now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ") + image.split('/')[-1])

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\me\\foo\\bar\\2019-10-03 12:38:48 300.jpg'
```

However the following works well. I prefer the previous format ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S '). What is the error?

```
fullfilename = os.path.join(r'''C:\Users\me\foo\bar''' , now.strftime("%Y %m %d %H %M %S ") + image.split('/')[-1])
```

Comment: `:` colon characters are not allowed in Windows filenames or paths. Use some other character instead.

Comment: @martineau : Thanks very much. It worked well.

Comment: That's good to hear. BTW, you don't really need to use `r`-prefixd and triple-quoted Windows paths if you're using the `/` forward slash separator — and you only the `r`-prefixif you ever use its native backslash \ separator character i.e. `r'C:\Users\me\foo\bar'` (which isn't necessary in Python).

Comment: @martineau : A good advice! Thanks again.

Comment: @martineau, colon is allowed in paths -- particularly in device names (e.g. "C:"; and "CON:" can even occur as the final path component) and stream names (e.g. "filename:streamname:streamtype"). It's also allowed even in filenames by some file systems such as the VirtualBox shared-folder file system, but it's better to not depend on the latter because allowing colon in filenames goes against platform standards.